# iOS 7 iPad webapp icons changing when multiple pages set

Tags: ipad, web-applications, ios7

I have 4 web apps that are webapp capable, each with a different URL on the same domain.  When i set a homescreen icon for all 4 on an iOS 7 iPad, the icons start swapping out and get mixed up with eachother as i set them.  To be more clear, here is the code for page 1.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test 1</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/iconPurple72.png" />
        <!-- iPad - landscape (748x1024) -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/ipadLandscape7.png"  media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />
        <!-- iPad - portrait (768x1004) -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="images/ipadPortrait7.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)" />
        <!-- iPhone - (320x460) -->
        <link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="/images/startup7.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 200px) and (max-device-width: 320px) and (orientation:portrait)" />
        <!-- enable full-screen mode  -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <!-- controls the appearance of the status bar in full-screen mode  -->
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />
        <meta name = "viewport" content = "width = device-width,initial-scale = 1.0, user-scalable = yes"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div><h1>this is test 1</h2></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

..pages 2,3 and 4 are exactly the same, except for this line:

```
 <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="/images/iconPurple72.png" />
```

...each page points to a different image in the same directory

the behavior is inconsistent, but can be seen on the device as well as the simulator.  When the ipad is restarted, the icons then appear normally, as they were originally set.  Sometimes, before restart, tapping an icon that has changed after setting another page can cause the iPad to lock up.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Are you linking to the other apps *within* each app? If you load a page with a different `apple-touch-icon`, it will replace the web app's icon on the home screen. (This is how web apps like [Sun](http://pattern.dk/sun/) update their icons.)

But it sounds like what you're experiencing is a bug in iOS 7 that causes weird things to happen when you have 3 or 4 or more web apps. The icons can be swapped, tapping one can open another, etc. Restarting your iOS device usually fixes this, though it's obviously a bug.

iOS 7 seems to be really buggy when it comes to web apps. For example, as you may have already noticed, browser dialogs (such as alert, confirm, HTTP authentication, etc) don't work, and neither do external links (be it a link to open in Safari or a phone number with the `tel` protocol). Launch images are stretched initially and scale in a very jerky way. Multitasking previews of web apps display a blank, white screen. It's odd that Apple would publicly release something this buggy.

Comment: i agree... ios 7 bug.  the icon swapping still exists with update 7.0.3 installed, and it is not limited to one domain.